# Using Ninject IOC to replace a factory

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject, factory-pattern

I've got a factory method inside a parser. Essentially as I load a token I look up the handler for that token, or drop through to the default handler. I've implemented this as a `switch` and as a `Dictionary<string,Type>` but both approaches require me to store the mapping somewhere else than the handler class.

We are using Ninject for IOC and so I've realized I can also do it using

```
kernel.Get<ITokenHandler>(tokenName);
```

but that doesn't save me storing the information on what token the handler can deal with in 2 locations. Is there a way I can decorate the handler so this gets mapped automatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I follow your question correctly, it sounds like you want to retrieve a named binding.  You didn't mention what version of Ninject you are using, but based on your code snippet, I am guessing you are using Ninject 2.0.  If that's the case then I would think this would suffice for your binding in your module:

```
Bind<ITokenHandler>().To<YourConcreteTypeHere>().Named(tokenName);
```

You bind as many concrete types to the same interface and differentiate them by name, and then retrieve them using the precise syntax you've specified in your question.

If I am missing something key, let me know.

Comment: A bit late to getting back here. What I was really after was a way to mark up the ITokenHandler concrete classes so that I could define the bindings where the Handler was declared. I've now gone with your example are all bar 1 of the bindings is of the pattern:

 Bind<ITokenHandler>().To<GenericTokenHandler<TokenTypeToConstruct>>().Named(tokenName);

Answer (score 1):

One technique I've used is to `Bind` stuff in such a way that you can require handing in of a parameter (in the context) at the point where you want someone to select something out.

Between http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Providers%20and%20the%20Activation%20Context and http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Contextual%20Binding you should be able to Bind things in such a way that you can say `Only(When.Context...)` to make the selection work?

Comment: Only just saw the other answer (as was +1'd on this). The other answer looks like a much more explicitly and clear approach so I'd definitely prefer it if possible - my approach is a more general approach for when built in ways arent possible.