# Injecting a dependency that requires parameters for initialization

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, inversion-of-control, ninject

I am using Ninject with Windows Phone application.

My logic includes IBarViewModel interface which is:

```
public interface IBarViewModel
    {
        double Width { get; set; }
        bool IsAchieved { get; set; }
        CornerRadius Corner { get; set; }
    }
```

Currently, there is only one implementatation of IBarViewModel - GenericBarViewModel.

All the IViewModel implementators will have to have these three main properties set at creation time.

I want to create an instances of these IBarViewModels at runtime from my code. How can I do it.

When I was programming against an implementation (the class was called simply `Bar`), I was just calling an object initializer like this:

```
_bars.Add(new Bar
                {
                    Width = _totalWidth,
                    IsAchieved = false,
                    Corner = new CornerRadius(5, 5, 5, 5)
                });
```

As per the answer to this question: [Inject value into injected dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153770/inject-value-into-injected-dependency) I can pass a parameter to ninject module.

**The only question remains**: will I have to carry my ninject kernel deep into the logic to do such parametrized dependency resolution?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227548/creating-an-instance-using-ninject-with-additional-parameters-in-the-constructor). Just make your class accept those parameters in the constructor and instruct ninject which values to supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be using IoC at all for this. It doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Why not simply let the `GenericBarViewModel` set the default values for the 3 properties, make it abstract, and let any other "Bar" ViewModel implementations inherit from the `GenericBarViewModel` ?

What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: Claus, that is exactly what I did yesterday. Thank you.