# Passing parent constructor arguments to nested class constructor with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I am trying to have ninject use a constructor argument from a parent class and pass it as an argument to the child when it is instantiated. How would I do my bindings to make this happen properly? I have been going through the examples and haven't found a solution.

```
public class MyModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ParentClass>().ToSelf();
        Bind<ChildClass>().ToSelf();
    }
}

public class ParentClass
{
    private string _index;
    private ChildClass _childClass;

    public ParentClass(string index, ChildClass childClass)
    {
        _index = index;
        _childClass = childClass;
    }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    private string _index;

    public ChildClass(string index)
    {
        _index = index;
    }

    public string Index { get; set; }
}

var kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyModule());
kernel.Get<ParentClass>(new ConstructorArgument("index", "MyIndex"));
```

So when I create my ParentClass instance, I want the ChildClass inside to have the same index value.

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153770/inject-value-into-injected-dependency

Comment: @Dennisch arguments can now be defined has `Inherited` so the answer you linked to is now ... let's call it superseded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your parameter to be inherited to child requests as follows:

```
kernel.Get<ParentClass>(new ConstructorArgument("index", "MyIndex", true));
```

This way the `ConstructorArgument` applies to all objects instanciated by the `Get` call. Of course the `ConstructorArgument` is only applied if there's a constructor parameter with a matching name. In your case the parameters are named `index` for both `ParentClass` and `ChildClass` so it works.

See also documentation of `ConstructorArgument` constructor [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Parameters/ConstructorArgument.cs#L71) and documentation of `IParameter` [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Parameters/IParameter.cs#L32)

### Update

In newer Ninject versions there's now the [TypeMatchingConstructorArgument](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Parameters/TypeMatchingConstructorArgument.cs) which matches for a type instead of a parameter name. However, if it's really a type as ubiquituous as `string` it makes more sense to "enclose" the configuration value in a new type, as shown by [Joseph Evenson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36462210/684096).

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar problem and initially went with the inherited constructor argument solution until one of my colleagues pointed out the downside - if you (or someone else) ever change the constructor argument name (index) your application will break.

An alternative to using named constructor arguments with inheritance would be to create a configuration type, create a new kernel for this request context and bind the configuration type (for that kernel) to a constant.  You'd end up with something like:

```
public class MyModule : NinjectModule
{
    private string _index;

    public MyModule(string index)
    {
        _index = index;
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ConfigurationType>().ToConstant(new ConfigurationType(_index));
        Bind<ParentClass>().ToSelf();
        Bind<ChildClass>().ToSelf();
    }  
}

public class ParentClass
{
    private string _index;
    private ChildClass _childClass;

    public ParentClass(ConfigurationType configuration, ChildClass childClass)
    {
        _index = configuration.Index;
        _childClass = childClass;
    }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    private string _index;

    public ChildClass(ConfigurationType configuration configuration)
    {
        _index = configuration.Index;
    }

    public string Index { get; set; }
}
```